# How do I collapse all displayed rows in a table?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am implementing a collapsible table, similar to how a treeview operates. There are 3 levels. In my current code, I can expand the 3 levels, however, when I then collapse the first level, level 3 is still showing.

Is there a way for me to collapse level 3 when clicking on level 1?

My jquery is

```
  $(function() {
    $(".firstlevel").click(function(event) {
    $(this).(".divider").filter(".secondlevel").toggle("slow");
    });

  $(".secondlevel").click(function(event) {
    $(this).nextUntil(".secondlevel").toggle("slow");
  });
});
```

HTML and Jquery is at https://jsfiddle.net/h4qacruv/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add attribute to every row corresponding to the row level as example:

```
<tr class="thirdlevel" data-level=3>
```

And use this code

```
$(function() {

  $("tr[data-level]").click(function(event) {
    //$(this).nextUntil(".divider").filter(".secondlevel").toggle("slow");
    var level = $(this).data('level');
    var that  = $(this);
    var siblings = $(this).toggleClass('shown').nextUntil('[data-level='+level+']:not(.divider)').filter(function(i) {
       var shown = that.hasClass('shown');
       return shown 
         ? $(this).data('level') == level + 1
         : $(this).data('level') >= level + 1;
    });//.toggle('show');

    if (that.hasClass('shown')) {
       siblings.show();
    } else {
       siblings.removeClass('shown').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Ronald, this expands all the "Level 3" options when the first "Level 2" is clicked?

Comment: oh, please try it again, i updated the script.. this time, it will only expand its adjacent high level rows, not all.